# How to run command SQLLoader Oracle in c#

Tags: c#

How to run command SQLLoader Oracle in c#. I try my sourcode for run this SQLLoader, but nothing happen and error "No process is associated with this object.". Please tell me how i fix it. Thanks.
This is my code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process1;
        process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        string strCmdLine;
        strCmdLine = @"/C SQLLDR XL/secreat@O11G CONTROL=E:\APT\LoadXL.ctl";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
        process1.WaitForExit();
        process1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to start your process using your variable `process1` like so:

```
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = strCmdLine;
process1.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
process1.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i put script above in my code, not happening and process SQLLoader not running.

Comment: I suggest that you put the command line into a batch file, put a `pause` command at the end and launch that batch file. This way, you can check the output for any error message.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I made it in c #. Why if I replace the command with ipconfig running. Was not able to run the process SQLLOader in c #

Comment: My suggestion was to start that batch file from C#. I assume, it simple can't find "sqlldr".

Comment: I was facing a similar problem. I had to write de command in a cmd file, and then: `process1.StartInfo.FileName = "file.cmd";`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlldr")
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = opts.WorkingDirectory,
        Arguments = "control="control.ctl" userid=usr/pass@XE log="data.csv.log" data="data.csv" bad="data.csv.bad"
     }
};
p.Start();
```